# Keil uVision5 .axf file is not created

Tags: c++, arm, keil

I have used Keil uVision5 to create a hex file for the target STM32F103VE and I was not able to generate the hex. Here is the error log.(I have already thoroughly searched for the answer):

> > linking...
> >     FromELF: creating hex file...
> >     .\CompileOutput\Main.hex: Error: Q0122E: Could not open file '.\CompileOutput\Main.axf': No such file or directory
> >     Finished: 0 information, 0 warning and 1 error messages.
> >     After Build - User command #1: C:\Keil_v5\ARM\ARMCC\bin\fromelf.exe --bin -o .\Output\Main.bin .\CompileOutput\Main.axf
> >     ".\CompileOutput\Main.axf": Error: Q0122E: Could not open file '.\CompileOutput\Main.axf': No such file or directory
> >     Finished: 0 information, 0 warning and 1 error messages.
> >     ".\CompileOutput\Main.axf" - 0 Error(s), 0 Warning(s).

Can anyone please help me get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a project with a similar error, and it turned out that we needed to disable cross-module optimization in the build options window.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue. In my case full path to project contain '!' char.
Try with simple path like 'c:\myProj'

Comment: i also got the same problem but solved it using a simple path